# Интуитивный конструктор SQL-запросов для веб-приложения

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток! Понадобилось сделать веб-приложение для статистики по информации из MySQL, приглянулся метод переброски данных в JSON через PHP, а потом приводить это в красивый вид через highcharts, как-то так:

```
    <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","stat",'xxxx', 'some_db');
if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");

$sql = "SELECT smth, smth_more FROM `table` WHERE `something_else` IS NOT NULL"

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or trigger_error(mysqli_error($con)." in ". $sql);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$row[0] = $r[0];
$row[1] = $r[1];
array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysqli_close($con):
?>
```

Но это неудобно в случае COUNT (хотелось-бы сделать это проще) и в случае требуемой статистики (не будешь же для каждого возможного запроса делать отдельный скрипт), поэтому хотел спросить о конструкторе запросов, когда клиент в UI выбирает "Мне нужно количество посетителей, которые оставили столько-то звёзд и заходили с такого-то по такое-то" (ну например). Есть ли готовые решения, или может какое-то дополнение? В крайнем случае, как это можно накостылить на js+php?

Comment: начинайте костылить и по ходу будете спрашивать то, что не  получается. не?

Comment: Даже не представляю, как это можно сделать. Я по сути даже PHP нормально не знаю, но прочесть документацию по mysqli было не сложно

Comment: ну так прочтите и по пхп.

Comment: Не язвите, пожалуйста. В таком случае выйдет только через год. Я же не прошу написать мне программу - если знаете, просто скиньте ссылочку или дайте примерную идею реализации, а дальше, если я не буду знать, буду спрашивать более конкретные вещи.

Comment: смысл вам расписывать идею реализации если вы пхп не знаете? тут же не на 3 минуты дело.